# How to install swoole on ddev?

Tags: php, ddev, swoole

I want to try [swoole](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src) (Asynchronous, coroutine-based concurrency library for PHP) in one of my project. I am using [DDEV](https://ddev.com/) (Docker-based PHP development environments) as my development platform on WSL2 (ubuntu 22.04). It need PECL to install swoole 5.1. Not sure how I can install it.

Answer (score 1):

After getting some help from Randy. I was able to figure out how to setup swoole development with DDEV on wsl2.

Luckly swoole is available in `deb.sury.org`. I added `webimage_extra_packages: [php8.2-swoole]` to the `.ddev/config.yaml` file and also exposed swoole ports.

```yaml
web_extra_exposed_ports:
  - name: swoole
    container_port: 9501
    http_port: 9501
    https_port: 9502
```

And then restarted the ddev `ddev restart`.

Also, I have binded the swoole daemon to port `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`. Like below code

```php
//file index.php
$http = new Swoole\Http\Server('0.0.0.0', 9501);

$http->on('start', function ($server) {
    echo "Swoole http server is started at http://0.0.0.0:9501\n";
});

$http->on('Request', function ($request, $response) {
    if ($request->server['path_info'] == '/favicon.ico' || $request->server['request_uri'] == '/favicon.ico') {
        $response->end();
        return;
    }
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $response->end('<h1>Hello Swoole. #' . rand(1000, 9999) . '</h1>');
});

$http->start();
```

Thats all you need to do. To run the swoole server. ssh to web container

```bash
ddev ssh
```

And then run this cli command

```bash
php index.php
```

I have posted this answer so it can help other in case they want to install swoole on ddev.

I hope there will be more better way to install swoole with ddev in future.